# Can I save an excel spreadsheet as a jpg using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jpeg

Does anyone know if it's possible to save an Excel Spreadsheet as a jpg using java? Currently, I am reading and manipulating Excel Spreadsheets in java using Apache POI. It's working great for everything else, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this question in their documentation or online.

Comment: Do you want to save a target range in excel sheet to a jpg image ?

Comment: What do you mean "save a .xlsx as a .jpg"? Save all contents as a jpg, or just certian components?

Comment: I only want to save certain cells, including formatting to a jpg file. It would be similar to a screen shot of only selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

There are some commercial libs to do so, another solution would be to use Apache POI to render your Excel as HTML and then convert this to an image utilizing a lib like this [java-html2image](https://github.com/hkirk/java-html2image)